# aws neo4j replication across regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, neo4j

Does anyone have any idea how to do a master to master replication of neo4j on AWS in different regions? I need to have one neo4j DB in USA, Asia, and Europe and I would like that my apache application connects from Europe to Europe Neo4j, USA to USA Neo4j and Asia to Asia Neo4j. For that, I would need that all 3 Neo4j be constantly synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j supports multiple datacenters. You basically organize your instances in groups indicating their location. The client then uses e.g. `bolt+routing://someneo4jhost.com?policy=europe` to indicate it want's to use servers of a specific group.

For details, read up https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/multi-data-center/